# Mockito Matchers.any(Class.class) returning null values when verifying a static method with PowerMockito

Tags: java, null, mockito, matcher, powermockito

I'm having an issue with Matchers.

I'm currently trying to verify that a certain static method is being called with the correct parameters.

```
@InjectMocks
Service service = null;

@Test
public void testMethod() {

service.methodToTest();

PowerMockito.mockStatic(Static.class);
PowerMockito.verifyStatic();
final Class2 check = getCheck();
Static.methodToVerify(Matchers.any(Service.class),Matchers.eq(check));
}
```

Problem is my test fails :

```
Wanted but not invoked metodToVerify(null,null);
```

I've checked that the Matchers are working fine on other methods but it seems to want to return null even though the actual method never takes null as parameters.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `PowerMockito.verifyStatic()` should be coming at the end. You must first call the static method, then verify. Right now, at the point of verification there are no calls to the static method, hence an exception is thrown.

Comment: @Vineet I don't have any exception, the test passes but the values created by the Matchers.any() aren't those that I expect. Therefore, the test fails. The verifyStatic() of PowerMockito should be before the static call of the method I want to verify.

Comment: `test fails` = exception. `verifyStatic()` tells it to check if the static method was called. Which method? The method in the next line. With what arguments? By the matchers used to describe it. So, you've set up a proper verification, but as a I said, you haven't made the actual invocation & hence it says `Wanted but not invoked`. Make an invocation prior to the `verifyStatic()` line.

Comment: @Vineet I see ! Got it ! Thank you very much :)